# Using Swift, why when pressing one UIStepper affect both steppers?

Tags: swift, uistepper

I am writing an application in Swift 3.0 using xCode.

I have two steppers on the iPhone and when I press one of them, both text boxes are affected. I only want one text box to be affected. ]

Does it have something to do with sender.value? How do I state specifically when I want only one label to be affected?

Here is my code:

```
    //the birthdate action that will increase or decrease the age
@IBAction func birthdateStepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    //when the age stepper is pressed, the value is sent to the textbox
    actualAgeLbl.text = String(sender.value)
}

//the weight action that will increase or decrease the weight
@IBAction func weightStepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    //when the weight stepper is pressed, the value is sent to the textbox
    actualWeightLbl.text = String(sender.value)
}
```

Here is before pressing the stepper:
[image: first picture before pressing stepper]

Here is after pressing the stepper
[image: second picture after pressing stepper]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My "guess" is, both a linked one or both of your `IBAction` - check the "Connection Inspector" of both your `UIStepper`s and feet what the "Value Changed" (I think) properties are linked to

Comment: This probably happened because you copied a stepper that was already wired up and then you added a second connection.  In the Storyboard, Control-click on the stepper and in the pop-up look at what is connected to "Value Changed".  Click the (x) next to the function you want to disconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are connected with same `@IBAction` for two stepper.
See below screen shot-

[image]